# How to count the number of days in Mysql where an event has happened in a row consecutively daily?

Tags: mysql, datediff, gaps-and-islands, row-number

[See table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZS1J.png)How to count the number of days in MYsql where an event has happened in a row consecutively daily?

```
CREATE TABLE MrDataConverter (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  num INT,
  controller_id INT,
  event_type INT,
  date VARCHAR(255),
  Desired output INT
);
INSERT INTO MrDataConverter 
  (num,controller_id,event_type,date,Desired output) 
VALUES 
  (1,42260,12,'2/27/2023 13:09',8),
  (2,42260,12,'2/26/2023 13:09',7),
  (3,42260,12,'2/25/2023 13:09',6),
  (4,42260,12,'2/24/2023 13:08',5),
  (5,42260,12,'2/23/2023 13:08',4),
  (6,42260,12,'2/22/2023 13:06',3),
  (7,42260,12,'2/21/2023 13:09',2),
  (8,42260,12,'2/20/2023 13:06',1),
  (9,42260,12,'2/19/2023 10:27',0),
  (10,42260,12,'2/19/2023 3:11',0),
  (11,42260,12,'2/17/2023 16:08',0),
  (12,42260,12,'2/17/2023 15:36',0),
  (13,42260,12,'2/17/2023 14:20',0),
  (14,42260,12,'2/17/2023 13:14',9),
  (15,42260,12,'2/16/2023 13:05',8),
  (16,42260,12,'2/15/2023 13:04',7),
  (17,42260,12,'2/14/2023 13:04',6),
  (18,42260,12,'2/13/2023 13:05',5),
  (19,42260,12,'2/12/2023 13:05',4),
  (20,42260,12,'2/11/2023 13:05',3),
  (21,42260,12,'2/10/2023 13:04',2),
  (22,42260,12,'2/9/2023 13:04',1),
  (23,42260,12,'2/8/2023 13:04',0);
```

I assume I need to do a datediff ( from the previous row )  and Row_number function?

```
SELECT row_number() over ( PARTITION BY controller_id ORDER BY date DESC) num, controller_id, date
FROM events 
WHERE controller_id = 42260
Order By date desc
LIMIT 200
```

Comment: This is a [tag:gaps-and-islands] problem. Islands specifically is what you're interested in. The solution will likely require using `LEAD()` or `LAG()`

Comment: If I have database 8.0.23, how will my code look like? Thank you!

Comment: Can you share you simple data as code not as image, and the expected data, so we can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the date strings converted to dates:

```
UPDATE MrDataConverter
SET `date` = STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i');
```

This gets you most of the way there:

```
SELECT
    num, controller_id, event_type, date,
    COUNT(IF(DATE(`date`) = prev_date, NULL, `date`)) OVER (PARTITION BY controller_id, grp ORDER BY DATE(`date`)) AS `desired output`
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        DATE(`date`) - INTERVAL DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY controller_id ORDER BY DATE(`date`)) DAY AS grp,
        LAG(DATE(`date`)) OVER (PARTITION BY controller_id ORDER BY DATE(`date`)) AS prev_date
    FROM MrDataConverter
) t
ORDER BY num ASC;
```

| num | controller_id | event_type | date | desired output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 42260 | 12 | 2023-02-27 13:09:00 | 9 |
| 2 | 42260 | 12 | 2023-02-26 13:09:00 | 8 |
| 3 | 42260 | 12 | 2023-02-25 13:09:00 | 7 |
| 4 | 42260 | 12 | 2023-02-24 13:08:00 | 6 |
| 5 | 42260 | 12 | 2023-02-23 13:08:00 | 5 |
| 6 | 42260 | 12 | 2023-02-22 13:06:00 | 4 |
| 7 | 42260 | 12 | 2023-02-21 13:09:00 | 3 |
| 8 | 42260 | 12 | 2023-02-20 13:06:00 | 2 |
| 9 | 42260 | 12 | 2023-02-19 10:27:00 | 1 |
| 10 | 42260 | 12 | 2023-02-19 03:11:00 | 1 |
| 11 | 42260 | 12 | 2023-02-17 16:08:00 | 10 |
| 12 | 42260 | 12 | 2023-02-17 15:36:00 | 10 |
| 13 | 42260 | 12 | 2023-02-17 14:20:00 | 10 |
| 14 | 42260 | 12 | 2023-02-17 13:14:00 | 10 |
| 15 | 42260 | 12 | 2023-02-16 13:05:00 | 9 |
| 16 | 42260 | 12 | 2023-02-15 13:04:00 | 8 |
| 17 | 42260 | 12 | 2023-02-14 13:04:00 | 7 |
| 18 | 42260 | 12 | 2023-02-13 13:05:00 | 6 |
| 19 | 42260 | 12 | 2023-02-12 13:05:00 | 5 |
| 20 | 42260 | 12 | 2023-02-11 13:05:00 | 4 |
| 21 | 42260 | 12 | 2023-02-10 13:04:00 | 3 |
| 22 | 42260 | 12 | 2023-02-09 13:04:00 | 2 |
| 23 | 42260 | 12 | 2023-02-08 13:04:00 | 1 |

I have used [DENSE_RANK()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_dense-rank) instead of [ROW_NUMBER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) as we don't want it to increment for the same date, when building the group. I have also used [LAG()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) so we can check against the previous date when incrementing the counter.

Comment: It is perfect actually!